# Why do I only have 3 options under 'Commerce' in Craft CMS Solo 4.5.6.1?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, menu

I have installed Craft Commerce 4.3.0 on Craft CMS Solo 4.5.6.1 on localhost (Xampp), but only have 3 options under 'Commerce' in the left-hand menu - Orders, Promotions, Store Settings.

[image: Image of menu issue in Craft Commerce]

Do I need to do anything else to activate the other options? Or has something gone horrifically wrong? Any pointers to where to start looking would be gratefully received. I am a complete noob to Craft.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Craft CMS!

A "Products" nav item will show under Commerce, once they have been configured and setup under "Product Types" in Commerce "System Settings".

However, Commerce "System Settings" will only show if Craft CMS environment is set to "dev".

Can you check what value "ENVIRONMENT" is set to in your Craft .env file? It should be set to "dev".

I've also noticed that you are missing a Craft "Settings" nav item, which suggests to me your project is not running in "dev" mode.

Further reading on how to configure that can be found here:

- https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/#env
- https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/general.html#devmode